# Extract month, date, and year from MMDDYYYY when given as a input in that format. Using only math

Tags: python

I cannot figure out how to get DD and YYYY separated.
For MM I did:

```
MMDDYYYY = int(input("enter" ))
month = MMDDYYYY // 1000000
```

Tried using % but could not figure out where to place it.

Comment: You said you tried using `%` but where did you try it exactly and what did you get back?

Comment: Python has a very powerful class for dates and times called `datetime`, you can benefit well from it.
here are some links to help:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp
and here is the documentation:
https://pypi.org/project/DateTime/

Comment: Hmmm, cheating on your homework… Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 2):

Using integer division (`divmod`) which returns quotient and remainder in one operation:

```
MMDDYYYY  = int(input("enter" ))
MMDD,YYYY = divmod(MMDDYYYY,10000) # extract the year
MM,DD     = divmod(MMDD,100)       # extract month and day
```

Or using divisions and modulo.  Division (`//`) by 10 eliminates the last digit.  Division by 100 eliminates the last 2 digits, and so on.  So you can strip the 4 digits of the year using a division by 10000 and you can eliminate the 6 digits of the day and year (to get the month) by dividing by 1000000.  A modulo of 100 extracts the last two digits (e.g. to get the day out of  MMDDYYY//10000). A module 10000 extracts the last 4 digits (e.g. the year)

```
MMDDYYYY  = int(input("enter" ))
YYYY      = MMDDYYYY %  10000       
DD        = MMDDYYYY // 10000 % 100
MM        = MMDDYYYY // 1000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus operator in conjunction with division [(try online)](https://onlinegdb.com/Utl5i3Dta)

```
month = MMDDYYYY // 1000000
day = MMDDYYYY % 1000000 // 10000
year = MMDDYYYY % 10000
print(month, day, year)
```

Comment: Providing an answer that doesn't help a student learn is not in the student's own best interest. While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `datetime`.

```
import datetime
MMDDYYYY = int(input("enter" ))
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(MMDDYYYY), "%m%d%Y")
```

You can simply get **year**, **month**, **date** as following:

```
date.month
date.year
date.day
```

Comment: This isn't "using only math" — in fact it's not used at all.